# How to get the C/C++ source code of the a secondary function of R?

Tags: c++, c, r, function

I was wondering what is the correct way to get the C/C++ source code of any secondary(to distinguish from the Primitive/Internal ones) function in R.
Related questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757435/read-source-code-of-an-r-function-including-c?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348008/how-to-see-source-code-for-functions-written-in-c-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function):

Mine is different so that I used "**secondary**" in my question. 
For example, the **read.table()** function, within **R** console I got:

```
>?read.table

read.table                package:utils                R Documentation

Data Input

Description:

     Reads a file in table format and creates a data frame from it,
     with cases corresponding to lines and variables to fields in the
     file.

Usage:
     read.table(file, header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"'",
        ......
```

Or

```
> getAnywhere(read.table)
A single object matching ‘read.table’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:utils
  namespace:utils
with value

function (file, header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"'", dec = ".", 

     ......

    attr(data, "row.names") <- row.names
    data
}
<bytecode: 0x560ff88edd40>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

Search the website I got:

https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/utils/src/utils.c

https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/utils/src/utils.h

How to get the **C/C++** source code of the **read.table** function instead of **R** code, if this is reasonable?

Comment: Does it have c/c++ code? I see nothing of it in https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/names.c

Comment: This is another clue I should have. I was not aware that names.c can provide some information. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The searchable R source code at https://github.com/wch/r-source is really useful for this:

- First we can look for the `read.table` [definition](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/utils/R/readtable.R#L58)
- The [actual data reading](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/utils/R/readtable.R#L185) is done by the [`scan`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/base/R/scan.R#L19) function which in the end uses

  ```
  .Internal(scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines,
  [...]
  ```
- Now `scan` is [mapped](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f65d2d48e23de36806ace3c3679fe91ffdff2747/src/main/names.c#L724)  to [`do_scan`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/1f1ff6a71a2891cd67ab9129671586e08f40045e/src/main/scan.c#L828)

So here you are: The underlying C implementation for `read.table` can be found in  `src/main/scan.c`, starting with the function `do_scan`.

Comment: Thanks Ralf!
Your answer is exactly what I was looking for and can't be more clear.

Comment: @Yifangt You are welcome. Feel free to up-vote/accept the answer.